# SSO Logout and login issue

Tags: php, yii, onelogin

I am trying to do a login functionality using SSO.
I have done login and logout successfully.

Problem is that I need to redirect to SSO login page at the time of logout from my application. It is done, but now when I paste my application url in the browser, it redirects me to SSO login page rather than my application page.

If I remove the cookie from the browser through settings, it will redirect me to my application login

I have tried to remove cookies through code but no luck,
`Yii::$app->response->cookies->remove('XYZ', true);`

Can any one please direct me to the right way?

We can't able to login to my application unless clear browser cookie / reopen browser

Framework Yii1
library used: oneLogin

Comment: Sounds correct so far. With SSO, the application login becomes obsolete...

Comment: So need to close clear browser cookie/ reopen browser always to access my application ..i have edited my question